# Can a function call itself?

Tags: solidity, tokens, ether, solidity-0.8.x, code

Can a function call itself...specifically, I am looking at this code and I can't figure out how this could work properly...the parameter vault would be the first parameter in the line that calls `updateYield()` so I don't see how this could work. I know you can have two functions with the same name but they have to have different parameters.

```js
function updateYield(uint256 vault) external nonReentrant {
        vault.updateYield();
        emit Events.UpdateYield(vault);
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the entire contract code and/or a link to the code on a block explorer if possible?

Comment: seems like you're essentially asking about recursive functions, at least if `vault` is `address(this)`, can you update your question with a code example?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that calls itself, the issue is ensuring that you don't get stuck in an endless loop that drains all your gas.

Take these contracts as an example:

*Assume we will always pass `1` as the input to the `only()` function.*

```js
contract CallOneself {


    function only(uint x) public {
        if(x < 7) {
            only(x + 1);
        }
        
    }
}
```

This function call used around 26533 gas.

```js
 function only(uint x) public {
        if(x < 77) {
            only(x + 1);
        }
        
    }
```

This function call used around 46095 gas.

```js
 function only(uint x) public {
        if(x < 777) {
            only(x + 1);
        }
        
    }
```

And this function call used up the entire default amount of gas on **Remix** and then reverted.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense but in this case the function (see below) takes a vault as a parameter (vault is an address) and then calls itself with vault as a parameter. I wonder if the developer intended to call a private function called _yieldUpdate since I know that is a common structure to use. I am pretty new to solidity and I wish I could write better tests but I can't really test it myself yet.

Code: function updateYield(uint256 vault) external nonReentrant 
{ vault.updateYield(); 
emit Events.UpdateYield(vault); }

Comment: @auditor_chick can you add the entire contract code in your question body? As well as a link to it on a block explorer if possible. Without the entire context it's hard to tell what the developer's intentions were, but you may be correct that the developer intended to call `_yieldUpdate()` but made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This concept is called `method overriding polymorphism` in OOP programming, it is achieved by making more than one function with the same name but with different parameters.

It's used to change the logic of the function when different parameters are passed.

Here is an example of a function that prints a number.

```
contract PrintNumber {
    event NumberPrint(uint256 number);

    function printNumber() public {
        printNumber(0);
    }

    function printNumber(uint256 number) public {
        emit NumberPrint(number);
    }
}
```

You can see this approach used by the Openzeppelin contract.

Here is a snipped code of the `approve` function from the `ERC20` contract, which uses polymorphism.

```
contract ERC20 {
    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 value) internal {
        _approve(owner, spender, value, true);
    }

    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 value, bool emitEvent) internal virtual {
        if (owner == address(0)) {
            revert ERC20InvalidApprover(address(0));
        }
        if (spender == address(0)) {
            revert ERC20InvalidSpender(address(0));
        }
        _allowances[owner][spender] = value;
        if (emitEvent) {
            emit Approval(owner, spender, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey I have heard of what you are talking about (although I didn't know the name of it before so thank you for that). But in this case the function has the same name and it takes the exact same parameters as well. I'm pretty sure the dev was intending to put _updateYield to call an internal function out of the corresponding library. But I was wondering what would happen if you tried to call a function that just called itself (same parameters). And it sounds like it is a lot more complicated than I thought

Comment: This is probably the case. When the function calls itself (recursion) it should have a condition to stop executing to not running forever. In solidity, if you made a function calling itself without any stopping conditions it will give an error when firing this function.